# Hard drive for Windows Surface tablet RT

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, windows-rt

I believe Windows Surface tablet RT come with solid state drive.
What is the speed rating of it, is it Serial ATA II or III? or 3?

Comment: The Windows Surface RT does NOT have a SSD.  It uses similar storage as the Apple iPad

Comment: @Ramhound, do you know the speed rating on that storage device?